# Migrating from Neo4j to Postgres

Tags: neo4j

Is there a way to migrate from Neo4j to Postgres? I have been trying hard and I have not been able to get any concrete solution. I greatly appreciate for the help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it will depend heavily on the reason why you want to move from Neo4j to Postgres, since the underlying model is quite different. Some stuff that is easy in a native graph, is hard or even impossible in pure Postgres.

Comment: I am trying to achieve something similar. Not sure if OP was able to do that?